# variable that is set to True in if statement never becomes False

Tags: python, list, pygame, iteration

I have a list of rectangles coordinates, that I'm iterating over to test for collisions with each one. The list is Like so: `self.rectangle_list = [(200, 30, 100, 10), (200, 60, 100, 10), (200, 90, 100, 10), (200, 120, 100, 10), (200, 150, 100, 10)]`. My code for the for loop is below.

```
        mouse_x, mouse_y = event_obj.pos # mouse_x, mouse_y are the coordinates of the mouse.
        for rects in self.rectangle_list:
            x, y, w, h = rects
            if x <= mouse_x <= x + w and y <= mouse_y <= y + h:
                self.hovering = True
            else:
                self.hovering = False
        print(self.hovering)
```

When I print out `self.hovering`, The only time It changes to True is when The mouse cursor is in the coordinates of the very last rectangle in the list.

When I move `self.hovering` under the `if` statement it works, but never sets `self.hovering` back to False while the `if` condition is not meet.

example code to reproduce the problem is bellow:

```
import pygame as pg


class RenderRects:
    def __init__(self, surface, rects_to_render=0):
        self.surface = surface
        self.rects_to_render = rects_to_render
        self.rectangle_list = []
        self.hovering = False

    def render_rects(self):
        y_padding = 0
        for rects in range(self.rects_to_render):
            y_padding += 30
            menu_items_rect = (200, y_padding, 100, 10)
            pg.draw.rect(self.surface, (255, 0, 0), menu_items_rect)
            if len(self.rectangle_list) > 5:
                del self.rectangle_list[4:]
            self.rectangle_list.append(menu_items_rect)

    def check_for_rect_collision(self, event_obj):
       #-----------------Where problem is-----------#
        mx, my = event_obj.pos
        for rects in self.rectangle_list:
            x, y, w, h = rects
            if x <= mx <= x + w and y <= my <= y + h:
                self.hovering = True
            else:
                self.hovering = False
        print(self.hovering)
        #-----------------Where problem is-----------#

    def update_rects(self, event_obj):
        if event_obj.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            self.check_for_rect_collision(event_obj)

def main():
    WIDTH = 800
    HEIGHT = 600
    display = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

    R = RenderRects(display, rects_to_render=5)

    running = True
    while running:
        for e in pg.event.get():
            if e.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False
                pg.quit()
                quit()

            R.update_rects(e)

        display.fill((255, 255, 255))
        R.render_rects()
        pg.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare `x <= mouse_x <= (x + w)` or `(x <= mouse_x <= x) + w`... or something else? You may want to look at Python's order of operations or add the correct parenthesis

Comment: Indent your print statement, you're printing out of the loop and will only see the last one in the list regardless of the contents

Comment: @Nick well i tried that both under the `if` statement and `else` statement but I didn't get any desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement has a problem:

```
if x <= mouse_x <= x + w and y <= mouse_y <= y + h:
                self.hovering = True
```

You can't chain less than/greater than as you do in: `x <= mouse_x <= x + w`. This really gets translated to:

```
if x <= (mouse_x <= x + w) ....
```

And since `True == 1` and `False == 0`, this means that if `mouse_x <= x + w` is `True`, `x <= (mouse_x <= x + w)` really becomes `x <= 1`

***Edit -- Added additional problem explanation*** (credit to [Michael Hoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6525140/michael-hoff) for the suggestion)

You also have a problem with your loop. In the loop, *for every rectangle pair*, you set the variable `self.hovering`. This means that you are continuously overwriting the value of `self.hovering` with the status of the *current* rectangle --- not if *any* of the rectangles are hovering.

Instead, since you care if `self.hovering` is *ever* `True`, you should only set the value in the `True` case:

```
self.hovering = False # assume it's not hovering at first
for rects in self.rectangle_list:
    x, y, w, h = rects
    if x <= mouse_x and mouse_x <= x + w and y <= mouse_y  and mouse_y <= y + h:
        self.hovering = True # now it will always be True
```

While this solves the loop issue, it's still a little bit inefficient, as it will continue looping over the pairs even after you find one that makes `self.hovering = True`. To stop looping when you find a "good" pair, you can use `break`, which just prematurely ends a loop.

```
self.hovering = False # assume it's not hovering at first
for rects in self.rectangle_list:
    x, y, w, h = rects
    if x <= mouse_x and mouse_x <= x + w and y <= mouse_y  and mouse_y <= y + h:
        self.hovering = True # now it will always be True
        break # exit the loop, since we've found what we're looking for
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I just learned about chained comparison recently, but I guess that is what I get for trying to be fancy. I did: `if mx > x and mx < x + w:` then added a second if statement under it: `if my > y and my < y + h:`.  And that worked perfectly.

Comment: Since you're just and-ing everything, you can actually leave it as one `if` statement: `if mx > x and mx < (x + w) and my > y and my < (y + h)`.  For other situations, you can just be explicit about the groupings using parentheses. For example, if you were `or`-ing `and` expressions: `if (mx > x and mx < (x+w)) or (my > y and my < (y+h))`

Comment: @Mr.Python: Indeed, this is a good answer. However, I don't see that it answers the core of your question: why it is only the "last rectangle" which decides over the value of `self.hovering`. @xgord: Maybe you could add a little hint to your answer pointing to the state issue within the loop. Just for future reference.

Comment: @xgord your second example, the one where you use break, is not working. I want `self.hovering = False` while I'm not hovering over any of the red rectangles. When I use your solution, `self.hovering` never equals `False` again after the first collision detection.

Comment: @Mr.Python did you include the line before the loop that sets `self.hovering` to False? if the example without `break` works, then the one with `break` will also work -- they're functionally equivalent -- i.e. the result is the same no matter which one you use. At the end of the function, `self.hovering` will equal false until the next time that function is called or something else changes the value.

Comment: @xgord Duh, I completely forgot the first line. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Mr.Python no worries, glad to help

Answer (score 4):

You set `self.hovering` inside the loop for *every* rectangle in the list. This means, after the loop the value of `self.hovering` corresponds to the "hovering state" of only the *last* rectangle.

I think you want to set `self.hovering = False` before the loop and in the loop set it to `True` if one of the rectangles matches your condition. This way, `self.hovering == True` holds only if at least one of your rectangles matches your condition.

This is a simplistic example for your problem:

```
numbers = [2,3,4]
contains_odd = False
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        contains_odd = False # this is wrong!
    else:
        contains_odd = True
# contains_odd == (numbers[2] % 2 == 1) == False
```

The solution would be:

```
numbers = [2,3,4]
contains_odd = False
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 1:
        contains_odd = True

# contains_odd == True
```

Comment: What about `break`-ing the loop when True is found?

Comment: This is a valid optimization. But at this point I found it more important to focus on the problem and to mention a very basic solution.

Comment: @MichaelHoff -_I think you want to set self.hovering = False before the loop and in the loop set it to True if one of the rectangles matches your condition._ Well isn't that what I am doing.

Comment: No, and exactly this is your problem. Say you have a list of three numbers [1,2,3] and a property `odd`. When you loop over the elements and set `odd = number % 2 == 1` then, after the loop, the variable `odd` will only characterize the last element and not all. That is because you set your boolean variable to the new value every time. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: @MichaelHoff Ok, i get you. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

The code is iterating through the list and self.hovering changes after each step. Therefore, the last rectangle determines which value is printed since its the only one influencing it since the print function is called **outside** of the loop.

**Update**: 
If you want it to be True if **any** of the rectangles fits, you can use:

```
any([x <= mouse_x <= x + w and y <= mouse_y <= y + h for x,y,w,h in self.rectangle_list])
```

Any is a built-in function that is given an iterable as argument. It returns True whenever any value within the iterable is True, otherwise False. In this case, it is given a list created by a so called list comprehension. The list comprehension is equivalent to the following:

```
lis = []
for x, y, w, h in self.rectangle_list:
    lis.append(x <= mouse_x <= x + w and y <= mouse_y <= y + h)
```

However, it does not require to create an empty list first and is therfore more compact.

Comment: thanks your solution also worked to perfection, But would you mind explaining your code a little bit more, as I've never used the built-in function `any()`